# Need a border for SSRS matrix child grouping

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

[image]

I have an SSRS matrix report with a parent grouping and two child groupings.  The parent is the name of the practice, the first child is the name of the person assigned to that practice, and the last child is the name of the location.  I'd like to have a border separating the names of the people assigned to the practice.  Without one it's difficult to tell where the start and end is for each assigned to person.

For example, in the image above I'd like to create a border between Cassandra Nesbeth and Cristabel Jerez.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding another column group header or footer based on if you need the separator before or after the group. In the column group footer or header set the width to something very small and give it a color to imitate a border.

Comment: Would I add the column group header/footer before or after the assigned to name header?  For example, it currently looks like Column Groups: PracticeName  AssignedTo  LocationName.  Would I add this before or after AssignedTo?

Comment: If you add it to the first child, the name of the person assigned to that practice, then you will visually separate the assigned to for each practice. If you assigning to the second group the location, then you will visual separate each assigned to and each of their locations.

Comment: I'm a bit confused how to add a group header.  I see the option to add another group with a group header, but not just a group header.

Comment: Find the AssignedTo column group in the column group view, below the report and to the right. Right click and you should see an option to create subtotal before/after and that should insert a header or footer for the selected group.

Comment: I can't get this to work.  It gives me the option to add a Total, not Subtotal.  If I add a Total before or after the Assignedto field, or even before the LocationName field it only gives a border separating the parent Practice Name.  I added an image of what I'm getting in the original post.

Comment: Then your report is not grouped as you think. If you have a parent group on AssignedTo and add a header then it would divide each of the assigned to's. I bet you have a group on parent Practice and the detail sorted by AssignedTo and Location. In order for this to work you need an assigned to detail group with a header. By the looks of it you don't have an assigned to detail.

Comment: You can try this as an alternative. On the column where you display the Assigned To name, add another column before it to the left. This should print before each name and you can add your virtual border there.

Comment: I updated my original post to show how my grouping looks.  Isn't this PracticeName as Parent and then assignedto and entityname as Child?

Comment: Ok, this is going from memory as I do not have that program in front of me. I will try to update this later this evening. However, you can put a column, a header column, between each instance of assigned to. It has to be linked to that group though. You may have an issue where the detail is in the header and no detail column exists or something like that where you need to shift your data over one column. It's tricky but doable. I'll try to message back later this evening if you are still stuck.

Comment: Yes, that would be great.  I just tried your latest alternative to add a column to the left and it looks really bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured out how to do this:

In the AssignedTo column I inserted a row Outside Group--Left.  I set the right border color to this new row to Black with a width of 1pt and then set the left border color of the already existing AssignedTo field to Black and a width of 1pt.  I then set the size of the new row to .01.

This is an example of how it comes out:

[image]